# Can not post the data after validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below are to validate a set of selectbox, however, it will not post and go to that post page after it pass the validation, how to fix it? I have added       return true; at the end but it seems not working, Thank you.

```
var $selects = $('form select[name^=select]'),
    values = [];

$(':submit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  values = [];
  $($selects).each(function() {
      if($(this).val()) {
          values.push($(this).val());        
      }
  });
    if(!values.length) {
        alert('Please select all categories');
        return false;
    }
  if(values.length < $selects.length || $.unique(values).length < $selects.length) {
    alert('Please select all categories and be unique');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```

Comment: there is  e.preventDefault(); that prevents the submission

Comment: but that is use for stop submittting and start  validation

Comment: @LeoChan return true/false do the work

Comment: it works, sorry i made mistake

Comment: I just don't know how this code would work when that e.preventDefault(); will be executed before the validation codes.. this is something like, "prevent the event" then "do nothing below"

Comment: Are you still have problems or it's good now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(':submit').click(function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault(); delete this.
```

It's preventing the default behavior of the submit button- submitting the form...

`return false` Does `e.preventDefault(); + e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: you means replace the return false to e.preventDefault(); + e.stopProprgoation()?

Comment: @LeoChan. No, I meant when you want the validation to fail, return false is enough. remove the `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Thanks, but if i remove this line, then it will post without any validation

Comment: @LeoChan. Try it, it will NOT.

Answer (score 0):

there is something that blocks to your event listener default action

```
var $selects = $('form select[name^=select]'),
            values = [];

        $(':submit').click(function(e) {
          //e.preventDefault(); <--remove this line
          values = [];
          $($selects).each(function() {
              if($(this).val()) {
                  values.push($(this).val());        
              }
          });
            if(!values.length) {
                alert('Please select all categories');
               e.preventDefault(); //<--PUT IT HERE~!!!
                return false;
            }
          if(values.length < $selects.length || $.unique(values).length < $selects.length) {
            alert('Please select all categories and be unique');
            e.preventDefault(); //<-- AND PUT IT HERE~!!!
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        });
```

Comment: if i remove this line, then it will post without any validation

Comment: I already revised my answer and look where i put the code that blocks the execution

Answer (score 0):

When you want to submit it you need `$('form').submit()`.